# Remove EditText autofocus to neighbour EditText

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 2 edittext in the same layout and I want that at the time one of the two is edited does not jump automatically on the other edittext. I tried everything! Help.

*this text is need to fill the textarea.....................................*
XML:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Axis name"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="@string/NomeAsse"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:cursorVisible="false"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="206dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="multiplier"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:text="@string/ValoreAsse"
            android:cursorVisible="false"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nm"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="---"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="23dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/kgm"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="---"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="23dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

android doesn't have any simple way to jump to `EditTexts`, you must to use `addTextChangedListener` and check length and jump to other programical

for example:

```
editTextOne.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
         if(s.length >4) // focuse to another editText
   }

   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {
   }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This code doesn't work, i add clearfocus to see if this work. but when the number that I insert exceeds the 4 characters is removed the focus but the keyboard remains, i want that i press enter on my keyboard i lost focus AND do not autofocus to other EditText AND close keyboard. solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I resolve in this way.

main activity -> onCreate() ->

`k.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if(i== EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
                    //Clear focus here from edittext
                    k.clearFocus();
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) rootView.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(rootView.getWindowToken(), 0);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });`

where k is the EditText.